# Dynamic Query for record fetch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a scenario like this

Databse 1
Inserting into a table :

```
ID    Person    
1     John
```

Before Inserting  a record I have to make sure that Person already exists which is handeled in other db

Database 2;

```
Person   Ou
JOhn     1
Shyam    2
```

Database 3:

```
Person   Ou 
Ram      5
```

....

Once record exists I have to insert the same record in that database. If nothing exists pop an error that person entered is invalid.

I have tried this code

```
 Select *,
        row_number() over(order by name)  'R'
        into #temp
from    sys.databases 
where   database_id not in (1,2,3,4,db_id(db_name()))

Declare @int i =1 
declare @person varchar(100) = person from inserting (nolock)
declare @dbname varchar(max)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
while (@i <= (Select max(R) from #temp))
begin 
Set @dbname = (Select name from #temp where R = @i)

Set @Sql = 'if exists (Select 1 from '''+ @dbname+'''..person where person = +'''@person'''+)'
execute sp_executesql @sql
Set @i = (Select max(R) from #temp))+2
else
set @i = @i+1
end

if @i> (select MAX(R)+1 from #temp)
begin
SET @sql = 'insert into ''' +@dbname+'''..person Select ID,person from person'
execute sp_executesql @sql
end
else
raiserror('No record esxists.',16,1)
```

But still I am unable to insert the record even if record exists. Any one can make this query better or any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Synonyms in your database in order to use person table from Database 2 and Database 3.

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Person2] FOR [Server2].[Database2].[dbo].[Person]
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[Person3] FOR [Server3].[Database3].[dbo].[Person]
```

After create your synonyms from Person table on database2 and database3, Person2 and Person3 behave such as Person table on Database1 and you can insert, update and delete rows from them without any problem.

Comment: There are not only two databases . If i know the databses i am ok with it . I can simply use synonms but i am not sure how many db's are there and also if client requests a new db is created and my query should handle it that is the reason y i used sys.databases eliminating system and current db.